# How do I remove gridlines (borders) in a React-Data-Grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I'm trying to remove gridlines from a basic table. Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-cell-editing-u2ood.

How do I do it? Do I need to manually override internal css classes or is there a props to do this?

Comment: Override style causing unwanted behaviour. `.react-grid-Cell { border: 0 }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CSS` to remove border, there is no `props` to do it.

```
.react-grid-Cell {
  border: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-cell-editing-omfs6?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no props to remove the border. You can do this by overriding the border attributes of class `.react-grid-Cell` .